# Comparing two numbers only compares the first number given jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two inputs. In the first one I have anual_rate1 and in the second I have anual_rate2. I need to compare if anual_rate2 is bigger than anual_rate1. If it is, it will let you continue, if not, it will fail. Anual rates are dinamically given by the user, so anual_rate3 has to be bigger than anual_rate2 and so on.

The problem is this. If for example, anual_rate1 is "320", and anual_rate2 is "321" it succeeds, so it is correct, but if anual_rate1 is "320" and anual_rate2 is "90" it succeeds to. It seems to me that it´s only taking into account the first number and not the entire number since "321" starts with "3" and "90" starts with "9".

Here is my code. Everything is inside in the document.ready function.

```
$(document).on("blur", '.anual_rate_class', function()
{

    var number = $(this).attr("id").replace("anual_rate", ""); // Takes the number of the anual rate from the id and put it in a variable.
    $(this).removeAttr("id").attr({id: 'anual_rate'+number}); // Gives again the id of the anual rate input since it was replaced to get the number.

    if( !$(this).val()) {
          $('#last_one_div'+number).attr({style: 'display:none'}); // Checks if the input is empty, if it is it wont´t succeed. And doesn´tn make available the nutton to continue.
    } 

    if( $(this).val() <= $('#anual_rate'+(number-1)).val()){ // Compares the last anual rate with the new one.
          alert('This anual rate is lower than the last one.'); // Alerts if it is not bigger than the last one.
          $('#last_one_div'+number).attr({style: 'display:none'}); // Doesn´t make available the button to continue.
          $(this).val('') // Clean the input field.
    } 

    if( $(this).val() > $('#anual_rate'+(number-1)).val()){ // If it is bigger, makes available the button to continue.
          $('#last_one_div'+number).attr({style: ''});
    } 

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.val()` will return a *string*. You need to convert the values to numbers first before comparing:

```
if( Number($(this).val()) <= Number($('#anual_rate'+(number-1)).val())){
```

Comment: Just to piggyback / clarify, in JS when you compare strings they are compared one character at a time, like you would if sorting words alphabetically. That is why "any" comes before "apple". If you try to compare numbers without expressly defining them as numbers, the same sorting algorithm will be used, so for example "182" will be considered "less than" "74".

Comment: It worked! Thank you! I have another question. Does it work also with decimals.

Comment: @Israel Sure, `Number` will convert anything that *can* be converted into a number into a number. It's not the same as `parseInt`